# How can i set the focus to an entry from my viewmodel in MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

I have an entry field and a picker element on my page. At app start the user has to select a process in the picker and after that the focus should be in the entry field automatically. Since I do the evaluation of the Picker element in the ViewModel (by a RelayCommand) I have the question if and if so how I set the focus from the VM.

My xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Mahle_ScannerApp_V3.MainPage"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Mahle_ScannerApp_V3.ViewModels"
         x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Image Source="logfox_logo_small.png"
            WidthRequest="200"
            Margin="0,10,0,0"/>

        <Picker Title="Vorgang auswählen"
                WidthRequest="270"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0,10,0,0"
                FontSize="20"
                TextColor="OrangeRed"
                x:Name="piProcess"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ScanProcesses}">
            <Picker.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior 
                    EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
                    Command="{Binding PiProcessItemChangedCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference piProcess},     
                        Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
            </Picker.Behaviors>
        </Picker>
        <Label x:Name="lblBarcodeOne"
               Text="{Binding LblBarcodeText}"
               FontSize="22"
               Margin="0,20,0,0"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

        <Border Stroke="#000000"
                Margin="0,10,0,0"
                StrokeThickness="2"
                StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20,20,20,20"
                Background="#C1CDC1"
                Padding="8,8,8,8"
                HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Entry 
                   x:Name="entryBarcode"
                   Text="{Binding EntryBarcodeText}"
                   WidthRequest="270"
                   FontSize="20"
                   TextColor="#838b83"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior 
                        EventName="TextChanged"
                        Command="{Binding TextEntryChangedCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference entryBarcode}, 
                            Path=Text}"/>
                </Entry.Behaviors>
            </Entry>
        </Border>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

My ViewModel (Snippet)

```
...
[RelayCommand]
async Task PiProcessItemChanged(object data) {
    ProcessType = Convert.ToInt32(data);
    if(ProcessType.Equals(0)) {
        LblBarcodeText = labelText[1];
    } else {
        LblBarcodeText = labelText[2];
    }
    
}
```

The itemchanged event works. But now a focus would have to be set in the entry field
I am still new in the area of MVVM and therefore I don't know exactly how to implement it.

Comment: To focus an `Entry` you have to call its `Focus()` method. This action belongs to UI, so I wouldn't place it in the viewmodel. You could link the `SelectedChangeEvent` to a code-behind method, even though I don't know if it keeps to be compatible with the command stuff.

Comment: have your VM raise a custom event that your View can subscribe to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic is part of the UI and it can be placed on the code behind.

There is an example how you can subscribe to change text event and handle it. You can still consume ViewModel properties if you save the reference of the BindingContext.

hope it helps

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _viewModel;
    public MainPage(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = mainViewModel;

        entryBarcode.TextChanged += EntryBarcodeOnTextChanged;
    }

    private void EntryBarcodeOnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var processType = e.NewTextValue;
        if (processType.Equals(0))
        {
            lblBarcodeOne = _viewModel.LabelText[1];
        }
        else
        {
            lblBarcodeOne = _viewModel.LabelText[2];
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, handling the onChange event in the code behind file was my first thought too. Thought there would also be the possibility to do that from the ViewModel

Comment: @DaveR It is not the question of possibility - a lot of things are possible, like god classes - it is a question of separation and resposibility

Comment: Definitely is possible to do that on ViewModel, but then you need to create an event and subscribe to it from code behind.. in my opinion it is just simplier to handle it from code behind.